# ExpandableListView: Add border to expanded group

Tags: android

please help me how to do this. I want this green border when a group in my ExpandableListView is expanded:

[image]

is there any way i can do this easily?

**Edit**:
I tried Abbas answer but it only wraps the parent view and not the whole group.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add these line in you expandable adapter:

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


// Your header layout id      
    RelativeLayout rl_header = (RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rl_header);

    if(isExpanded)
    {

        rl_header.setBackground(_context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.header_background_black));
    }
    else
    {

        rl_header.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.header_background);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is similar to the answer above.. It only wraps the parent view and not the whole group. In this case it only wraps "Carpentry & Woodworks" alone

Answer (score 0):

Set a selector as background for Parent Items (Carpentary and Woodworks, etc.).

Add a new background file named **item_selector.xml** in **drawable** folder.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:color="@color/green" android:width="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

set background for your View Item in `xml` code. I can only guess here since you didn't provide any code.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@drawable/item_selector">
    <TextView></TextView>
    <ImageView></ImageView>
</LinearLayout
```

And finally when you expand the view i.e. onClick

```
expandableView.setSelected(true);
```

Don't forget to change the selection state back when another view is selected.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I already tried doing this. but this would only wrap the parent view and not the whole group.. in this case it only wraps "Carpentry & Woodworks" alone...

Comment: added picture above.

Comment: @YellowJ then perhaps you should add some code in your question, so we can better understand the problem. Preferably from `ParentItem.xml` and `ChildItem.xml`.